# Store large amounts of images efficiently in Unity Android/iOS

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine, architecture, storage

I am thinking of an architectural decision on how to solve the following problem:

A **mobile** application developed with **Unity** receives images from a **server** **periodically**.
To allow fast reload times of reoccuring images, I want to **cache** as much of these images as possible on the **client** side **persistently**.
The images do not need to be protected and **may be viewed** by the users outside the application.
I currently do this by storing the downloaded images on the SD card.
With this approach I have the following concerns:

- **Lots** of small files may slow down the phone and/or the application; from my understanding many small files are worse for the memory health than one large (?)
- **Removing stale images** to preserve available disk memory seems rather difficult

One thing, that came to my mind was using **SQLite** to store the images, however, I learned, that storing a lot of blobs in a db is not recommended.
I could store the file paths of the images and my second concern would be addressed that way, however the first one persists.

There is no way to pre pack the images in the assets folder, they will always be **received from the server** during runtime.

Am I right with my concerns and what is the best practice when facing this problem?

Greetings and many thanks,

Codehai

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the impacts of many files on memory health, but some suggestions come to mind:

- You could gzip images when writing them to disk and gunzip them before use in order to reduce space
- For managing the removal of old images, perhaps you could create a "garbage collection" task that runs on an interval to trim the oldest photos in order to fall underneath a max memory footprint or to enforce a max age for images
- Using HTTP caching and a CDN (like CloudFront) could help with minimizing the response time when requesting images over the network